# What is the name of this author?

Tags: military, catholic-church, book, literature, pope

I'm a newbie here so please forgive me if this kind of questions are not allowed.

Couple days ago my friend wanted me to find an author and gave me some hints about it. I did lots of researches but couldn't find anything. He doesn't tell me who this is and this drives me crazy. I'm spending my whole day at work just to find this author but no chance.

So,

- This author is also a soldier and got wounded in a war, such that he had to left the army.
- And he was a masonic lodge member as from his 20's.
- He had an accident about his 30's and his one foot became dysfunctional.
- He wrote a book about a ruler/emperor, and when this was first published, the author was in his 60's.
- He wrote something about Felice Peretti di Montalto and these were turned into a book by adding 3 different topics (this is probably the book mentioned in the previous hint).
- He received death threats and had to move from the country where he lived. And for the rest of his life, he lived in the city he moved to after this incident.
- In the city where he died, there is a street named after his surname.
- He has a famous book and he underestimates Italy in that book.

I assumed this author was a man but it could be a woman of course.

Comment: Is this author actually famous? That is, will most people recognise their name when they hear it?

Comment: @SteveBird Asked my friend but he didn't say if the author is famous or not. But he said that the author has a famous book and the author underestimates Italy in that book. That's all he said.

Comment: What "lodge" was he a member of? Freemasons? Elks? Oddfellows? Knights of Columbus? There are a large number of possibilities.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Oh, sorry. It's masonic lodge. I'm not native in English, so I used a dictionary for that word and it gave me just "lodge". I'm adding this info to the question now.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into the question, but instead use the Answer box below. In most SE communities it's okay to self-answer.

Comment: @shoover Oh, okay sorry for that. As I said, I'm new here. I'm fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer, not by research but from my friend. The person was:

***Johann Wilhelm von Archenholz***

- He served as a company commander in the Seven Years' War. He was discharged from the army after being badly wounded in this war.
- He has been a member of the Masonic lodge since the mid-1760s.
- He fell off a horse in Rome in 1780, and one foot was permanently paralyzed.
- He was threatened with guillotine in France and therefore left France and settled in Hamburg. Meanwhile, he wrote a book about the life of Gustav I of Sweden. (4th and 6th tips)
- His writings about Felice Peretti di Montalto (Pope Sixtus V) are collected in the book 'Kleine historische Schriften' with adding 3 other titles. (This is not the book mentioned in the 4th tip :) )
- He lived in Hamburg until his death, and in Hamburg there is a street (Archenholzstraße) named after his surname.
- His most famous book 'England und Italie' made a huge impact in Europe. In the book, he compared the political situation of both countries and belittled Italy against England. Goethe harshly criticized this condescending attitude at that time.

Comment: I have now read part of volume two of ["England und Italien"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/England_und_Italien/m2W6C3WaRykC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PP9&printsec=frontcover) which covers Italy and I have to say it is a very interesting read. The description of Italy and its constituent states is indeed harshly critical and the tone at times condescending. Every positive remark is immediately countered by a related negative observation. The author claims in an afterword that this not due to ill will on his part, or because he did not find his stays in Italy enjoyable.

Answer (score 3):

[Count J. A. Huebner](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_Joseph_Alexander_H%C3%BCbner) roughly matches your description.

Hübner wrote both a famous book about Sixtus V and a famous memoir on Italian politics. He was not in the military but he was a diplomat. In his youth he worked for the Austrian intelligence. I don't know if he was ever wounded or threatened but in 1848 he was held hostage by the Milanese revolutionary government. He never spent a lot of time in one place, though, travelling extensively both on diplomatic missions and for his own pleasure. He died in Vienna. I couldn't find any better candidate.

Comment: You should include the key 'matches' between the clues and your suggestion (because even Wikipedia pages can rot).

Comment: Hübner wrote both a famous book about Sixtus V and a famous memoir on Italian politics. He was not in the military but he was a diplomat. In his youth he worked for the Austrian intelligence. I don't know if he was ever wounded or threatened but in 1848 he was held hostage by the Milanese revolutionary government. He never spent a lot of time in one place, though, travelling extensively both on diplomatic missions and for his own pleasure. He died in Vienna. I couldn't find any better candidate.

Comment: @Iguess Thanks for your answer but that was not correct. I added the answer if you want to look.